# spring security acl administration permission

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I try to enforce a new app with spring security ACL and after some reading I have a problem with permissions for every ACE. I was expecting that if a principal has the administration permission (16) over an domain object instance to be able to access a method with this annotation:

```
@Override   
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
public List<Project> findAllProjects() {
    TypedQuery<Project> tq = em.createNamedQuery("Project:findAll", Project.class);
    List<Project> projects = tq.getResultList();
    return projects;
}
```

but

```
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'ADMINISTRATION') OR hasPermissions(filterObject,'READ')")
```

it seems to work.
So, my question is : Aren't these permissions hierarchical?
I mean, why do I have to explicit specify admin permission on a method that has read permission? Isn't admin "bigger" than read ?
I was thinking that if I grant to a user an admin permission that hte user will be able to access all the methods/objects protected with "lower" operations (C,R,U,D) than admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018264/how-do-i-use-the-mask-field-in-acl-entry-table-in-spring-security-3-1/26779951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, permissions are not hierarchical out-of-the-box.

If you want them to be hierarchical, you need make a custom implementation of `PermissionEvaluator` or similar.

Comment: This answer seems to provide such a custom implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174711/5134722