# How to interpret hasPermission in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am new to spring security. How do I interpret this?

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(null, 'opetussuunnitelma', 'LUONTI')")
     OpetussuunnitelmaDto addOpetussuunnitelma(OpetussuunnitelmaDto opetussuunnitelmaDto);
```

Which method from the permission evaluator would get called? I think the one with three parameters would get called in this case. It is checking if the current user has the 'LUONTI' permission on the target of type - 'opetussuunnitelma' . Am I right? Can't we just not include "null" and pass only two parameters. I read that the first argument ( the Authentication object) is not supplied.

```
+public class PermissionEvaluator implements org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator {
+
+    @Override
+    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
+        LOG.error(" *** ei toteutettu *** ");
+        return true;
+    }
+
+    @Override
+    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
+        LOG.error(" *** ei toteutettu *** ");
+        return true;
+    }
+
+    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PermissionEvaluator.class);
+}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Which method from the permission evaluator would get called?

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission)
```

Would get called.

> I read that the first argument ( the Authentication object) is not
>   supplied.

It's not explicitly supplied in your annotation, but implicitly supplied by Spring. Your annotation should just read

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#opetussuunnitelmaDto, 'LUONTI')")
```

Ideally I would check if they're even authenticated before performing the authorization.

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#opetussuunnitelmaDto, 'LUONTI')")
```

**Update to your comment**

Basically you can either call the PermissionEvaluator with either:

```
hasPermission('#targetDomainObject', 'permission')    // method1
hasPermission('targetId', 'targetType', 'permission') // method2
```

Authentication will always be supplied by Spring. In your case, you are calling hasPermission the following way

> hasPermission(null, 'opetussuunnitelma', 'LUONTI')")

which would match **method2**, but passing in a null id doesn't make sense, what entity are you going to target the permission check on? Based on your method that you're applying the @PreAuthorize on,

> OpetussuunnitelmaDto addOpetussuunnitelma(OpetussuunnitelmaDto
>   opetussuunnitelmaDto);

it may make more sense to call **method1** since you seem to have something that resembles an target domain object.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me if the use of "null" serves any purpose here?

Comment: When I add @PreAuthorize annotation to a method in the controller, it works like charm. But, doesn't work with a service method. Any specific reasons?

Comment: @Arun perhaps some of the answers here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58755986/5134722

Answer (score 9):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033890/5134722) has already got to the heart of what it seems the OP was truly asking. I will augment that answer with a slightly deeper dive into what is going on behind the scenes with the `hasPermission` expression.

### Recap

Let's first recap on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033890/5134722). The answerer detected that the OP really meant to be using an annotation with two parameters:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#opetussuunnitelmaDto, 'LUONTI')")
```

The confusion arose because the OP saw a method `hasPermission` in the code which took three parameters, and couldn't figure out what to pass for the first parameter. The answerer confirmed that the Spring framework itself provides that first parameter, namely the `Authentication` object, so in the annotation we only need to pass two arguments.

### Deeper Dive

To understand what's going on in a little more detail, let's analyse how `hasPermission` works in Spring OOTB. I won't go into every last detail, but will sketch out the main flow of what is happening. Hopefully this will shed light not only upon which overloaded method is linked to the `hasPermission` SpEL expression, as the OP asks, but also will reveal a bit about how the entire ACL framework interprets the `hasPermission` expression under the hood; this will give us a greater confidence of what the `hasPermission` expression means, and thus how to interpret and use it.

So let's start from the top.

#### A Small Note on Pre/Post Authorization

To understand the `hasPermission` expression we really need to understand pre/post authorization. However, since the OP doesn't ask about that, it's assumed to be known, and I won't go into much detail about method protection via the `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations. The reader is referred [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) for more info on that. Suffice it to say here that we'll assume the `hasPermission` expression is embedded in such an annotation in order to protect a method or return object. The `hasPermission` expression in turn will evaluate to true or false. If it evaluates to true, the Spring framework will allow the method call to proceed in the case of pre-authorization or will allow the object to be returned in the case of post authorization. Otherwise, it will block access. That's enough about those annotations. What we really want to know is how Spring interprets the `hasPermission` expression itself, to arrive at a true/false value.

#### The Permission Evaluator Class

So, `hasPermission` will evaluate to true or false. But how? Well, as alluded to by the OP, Spring delegates permission evaluation to the `PermissionEvaluator` object which is nested inside the `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` Bean. If you've set up Spring ACL, then it's likely you've registered the `AclPermissionEvaluator` as the permission evaluator for Spring to use. For example, if you configured Spring ACL with code you might have something like this:

```
@Bean
public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler 
  defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler
      = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator 
      = new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

Had you not done that, the default permission evaluator in place would have been the `DenyAllPermissionEvaluator`, which as I'm sure you've guessed would just deny permission in all cases: a safe default for sure.

#### From Annotation to Method

So, with the `AclPermissionEvaluator` class plugged into the Spring security framework as above, all `hasPermission` expressions in the Spring expression language (SpEL) will be delegated to the `AclPermissionEvaluator` for evaluation. I have not looked into the exact details of how the SpEL expression eventually ends up resulting calling upon methods within `AclPermissionEvaluator`, but I don't think such knowledge is needed to interpret what the `hasPermission` expression means. IMO, all that's necessary to know, at this level, is which annotation results in which method call. This has already been covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033890/5134722). But let me recap it here. First of all, we note that the `hasPermission` method is overloaded in the `AclPermissionEvaluator` and indeed in any implementation of `PermissionEvaluator`. One of the methods takes 3 arguments and the other takes 4 arguments:

```
//3-Arg-Method
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission);

//4-Arg-Method
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission);
```

On the other hand, the `hasPermission` expression has two use cases also. One of them passes in 2 arguments, and the other passes in 3 arguments. These were already pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033890/5134722). But let's label them here as expressions, rather than methods, so as not to confuse the two:

```
hasPermission('#targetDomainObject', 'permission')    //2-arg-expression
hasPermission('targetId', 'targetType', 'permission') //3-arg-expression
```

We can now link the two:

1. If the `//2-arg-expression` is used, then the `//3-Arg-Method` is called.
2. If the `//3-arg-expression` is used, then the `//4-Arg-Method` is called.

Where do the methods get their extra argument? Again, this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033890/5134722), but to recap, the extra argument that the Spring security framework provides based on the security context is the first argument in both cases, namely the `Authentication` parameter by the name of `authentication`. I haven't looked into how the Spring framework does this exactly, but for me it was enough to just know that Spring security can get an authentication object in this context.

OK, but what about the other arguments? Let's see this next. To avoid this answer getting too large, I'll just focus on the case where the `//2-arg-expression` is used and the `//3-Arg-Method` is called.

#### Parameters to the `hasPermission` Method

As mentioned, let's just focus on this method:

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission);
```

As discussed already, the first argument, the `authentication` object is inferred via Spring security. I haven't looked into exactly how that happens, but I believe all we need to know for the purposes of this post is to understand that the authentication object contains:

1. The user i.e. the principal e.g. "Alice"
2. All the roles i.e. authorities that have been granted to that user e.g. "admin" or "editor"

In Spring ACL, we refer to a principal such as "Alice", or an authority such as "editor" using the common term SID. As such, the `authentication` object contains not just one SID, but a whole list of them. The order of this list matters, as we'll see later on.

The remaining parameters to the `hasPermission` method are passed via the `hasPermission` expression. These are both typed as `Object`. Again, I'll just focus on one use case for the sake of keeping this post a bit shorter. Indeed, let's focus on a slightly modified version of the original use case that the OP mentions:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#opetussuunnitelmaDto, 'READ')")
OpetussuunnitelmaDto addOpetussuunnitelma(OpetussuunnitelmaDto opetussuunnitelmaDto);
```

1. The usage of the # symbol in the sub-expression `#opetussuunnitelmaDto` is a way of specifying in SpEL that the `opetussuunnitelmaDto` parameter of the method `addOpetussuunnitelma` is passed in as the `targetDomainObject` of the `hasPermission` method.
2. The `'READ'` parameter is simpler: it's simply passed as a `String` straight to the `permission` parameter of the `hasPermission` method.

#### Extracting Useful Info from the Parameters

So, we now know how all the parameters are supplied to this method:

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission);
```

But parameters of type `Object` are never much use. Spring ACL needs to convert those parameters into information is can use to access the relevant ACL info from the database and do its permission checking. It does so by delegating to the `checkPermission` method, which extracts info as follows:

1. An ordered list of SIDs is obtained from the authentication object. For example, suppose the user "Alice" is logged in and she has the "admin" and "editor" permissions. Then this list will contain SIDs for "Alice", "admin" and "editor". The variable that stores that list is `List<Sid> sids`. Now, the order of this list is important. Let's consider why. Suppose you are using a mixture of grant plus deny ACEs. For example, we may grant access to some object to all editors. But then we might deny it to the user Jane. If Jane, who is an editor, tries to access the object, do we deny access on the basis that she's Jane, or grant on the basis that she's an editor? For this reason, the order of the list of SIDs is important. The first one to match wins. So what controls the order in which SIDs are returned? Well, that responsibility lies with the `SidRetrievalStrategy`, which by default is `SidRetrievalStrategyImpl`. By looking at this class's `getSids` method, we see that the principal SID, i.e. Alice, is given the prime position in the list. Thereafter follow the granted authorities. I haven't delved into the detail of how the authorities themselves are ordered, but it looks to me like it's just insertion order, except for the case where role hierarchies are in play, in which case the order probably follows the hierarchy. It makes sense to me that Alice would be granted the first position in the list. If Alice herself has been granted/denied access to anything, then it's intuitive to think that that overrides anything she's been granted based on a role she has. For example, if we want to deny access to Alice, even though she's an editor, then that specific denial should take precedence. On the flip side, we might want to disallow all editors from accessing an object but make an exception for Alice. Again, putting Alice first in the list ensures this logic is enforced.
2. The permission object, which up to now is just an `Object`, is resolved into a list of `Permission` objects via the method `resolvePermission`. The variable that stores this is `List<Permission> requiredPermission`. Now, recall that we are focusing on the case where this permission is a single string, namely `"READ"`. In this case, if Spring is left to its default behaviour, the permission resolver will use reflection to check this `String` against all the static constants in the class `BasePermission`, and will return the matching constant. The code that actually does the final conversion is the method `buildFromMask` in the class `DefaultPermissionFactory`. If no member of `BasePermission` is found whose name matches `"READ"`, then the code will throw an exception. Indeed, in the case of the OP's use case, the permission given is `"LUONTI"`, which won't match anything in `BasePermission` - in that case the developer would need to override `BasePermission` or create their own class for permissions. But we won't cover that here. We also note that in general, the expression might result in a list of permissions, but in our specific case we just get one permission for the one String that was passed into the SpEL expression.
3. The ACL itself, is retrieved based on the object. Actually, within the `hasPermission` method, the domain object gets converted to an object ID, which `checkPermission` then uses to query the DB for that ACL via the ACL service: `Acl acl = this.aclService.readAclById(oid, sids);`.

Spring now has all the information it needs to do a YES/NO check: does the currently logged in user have access to this object or not? It does so by delegating to the `isGranted` method on the `PermissionGrantingStrategy` Bean. By default, this is implemented via the `DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy`.

#### `isGranted` ...We're Almost There

When we look at this method, it becomes apparent that order is indeed important for the list of ACEs within the ACL and the list of SIDs. Order is somewhat important for the list of permissions too, but less so - all it determines is which permission is interpreted as the "first" permission that denied access, if the result of the (public*) `isGranted` expression evaluates to false; and from what I can see this is just used for logging/debugging purposes so that an admin can try fix the most likely permission that's broken first.

For the ACEs and SIDs, order is indeed important because the first matching ACE to an SID takes precedence, and no other matches are performed for that permission. If the match results in an allow, then the entire `isGranted` function returns true. Else if there is no match for that permission or if there is a deny, the code moves on to the next permission and tries that. In this way, we can see that the list of permissions are checked with an OR type of logic: only one of them need to be granted for `isGranted` to succeed.

What about the actual logic that checks does a given ACE match a given permission and SID? Well, the SID bit is easy: just get the SID field off the ACE and compare: `ace.getSid().equals(sid)`. If the SIDs match, an overloaded `isGranted` function is called, which just compares the masks:

```
protected boolean isGranted(AccessControlEntry ace, Permission p) {
    return ace.getPermission().getMask() == p.getMask();
}
```

IMO, this method really should have been called something like `isMatching` because it should return true for both allow (i.e. grant) AND deny type of permissions. It is just a matching function - the allow/deny behaviour is stored within the `ace.isGranting()` field. Furthermore, the function name `isGranted` is overloaded*, confusing matters even more.

There is also [some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9018264/5134722) around why this doesn't use bitwise logic, but don't worry, you can easily override the method if you like, as specified in the answers to the linked question.

#### Conclusion

To recap, the OP originally asked:

> How to interpret hasPermission in spring security?

This answer deep dives into the machinery of `hasPermission` to give an understanding of how to interpret it. In summary:

1. The `hasPermission` SpEL expression links to one of the overloaded `hasPermission` methods in the `AclPermissionEvaluator` in Spring ACL, with the `Authentication` object filled in automatically by Spring security.
2. Parameters to the `hasPermission` SpEL expression trickle down through the Spring ACL machinery.
3. Spring ACL checks three lists: SIDs, permissions, ACEs (the ACL itself) and for two of these lists, the order matters to determine the final YES/NO answer to the question "Does the user have access to this object?"
4. Only one ACE match is performed per permission, and the match is based on SID and the overloaded `isGranted` function, which can be overridden e.g. if the developer wants to use bitwise logic.

#### Footnotes

*There are two version of the `isGranted` function. The public one does indeed check if some permission in the list is granted to some SID. Wherease the protected one really should have been called something like `isMatching` as it checks for matching ACEs.