# When adding @PreAuthorize to a service class: "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, fortify

I have a Spring Boot controller that works fine and has the following declaration:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/our")
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@Api(value="our", produces="Our data")
public class OurController {
```

When I run the Fortify static analysis tool on our code, it complains about our service class saying:

> Without proper access control, the method findAll() in OurService.java can execute a SQL statement on line 36 that contains an attacker-controlled primary key, thereby allowing the attacker to access unauthorized records.

So I tried to add the @PreAuthorize annotation to our service class like so:

```
@Service
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public class OurService {
    private final OurRepository ourRepository;

    public OurService(OurRepository ourRepository) {
        this.ourRepository = ourRepository;
    }

    public Page<Our> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return ourRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public Page<Our> findAll(Specification<Our> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        return ourRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
    }
}
```

But when starting up our application, it failed with the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` in your configuration class?

> - The prePostEnabled property enables Spring Security pre/post    annotations
> - The securedEnabled property determines if the @Secured annotation    should be enabled
> - The jsr250Enabled property allows us to use the @RoleAllowed    annotation

In order for `@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` to work you need to add that annotation in your configuration class.

You can read this [Introduction to Spring Method Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

The failure was coming from a class annotated with `@Component` and that implements the `ApplicationRunner` interface.

I had to add the following code to its constructor:

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getClass().getName(), "ROLE_USER", authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try without the value keyword in @PreAuthorize.

For example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

Comment: Ok did you create a SecurityContext object in your class?

Comment: If you don't have SecurityContext object you can check here:
https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security